# Cannot update the grub with correct command, how to do it

Tags: grub2

$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

is the command I run and I get below

/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: quiet: not found
my problem is in this link

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vC6ZX4HWn8/plain/

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /etc/default/grub /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.10 on sda1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro quiet splash
df -Th / : /dev/sda1      ext4  109G   61G   43G  59% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: BEH6110H.86A.0016.2011.0118.1128 from Intel Corp.
This installed-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc grub1 , grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ng, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0949dc21
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048 232441855 232439808 110.8G 83 Linux
sda2       232443902 234440703   1996802   975M  5 Extended
sda5       232443904 234440703   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:120GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ADATA SP550:;
1:1049kB:119GB:119GB:ext4::boot;
2:119GB:120GB:1022MB:::;
5:119GB:120GB:1022MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                             
â”œâ”€sda1 ext4     a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd 0949dc21-01                                
â”œâ”€sda2                                               0949dc21-02                                
â””â”€sda5 swap     5d36fa99-ed26-4cec-9329-015463d13ad7 0949dc21-05                                

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                       42.4G  56% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


====================== sda1/boot/grub/menu.lst (filtered) ======================

# menu.lst - See: grub(8), info grub, update-grub(8)
#            grub-install(8), grub-floppy(8),
#            grub-md5-crypt, /usr/share/doc/grub
#            and /usr/share/doc/grub-legacy-doc/.
## default num
# Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
# the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
#
# You can specify 'saved' instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
# is the entry saved with the command 'savedefault'.
# WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not use 'savedefault' or your
# array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
default     0
## timeout sec
# Set a timeout, in SEC seconds, before automatically booting the default entry
# (normally the first entry defined).
# on ec2, with no console access, there is no reason for a timeout.  set to 0.
timeout     0
## hiddenmenu
# Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
hiddenmenu
# Pretty colours
#color cyan/blue white/blue
## password ['--md5'] passwd
# If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
# control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
# command 'lock'
# e.g. password topsecret
#      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
# password topsecret
#
# examples
#
# title     Windows 95/98/NT/2000
# root      (hd0,0)
# makeactive
# chainloader   +1
#
# title     Linux
# root      (hd0,1)
# kernel    /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda2 ro
#
#
# Put static boot stanzas before and/or after AUTOMAGIC KERNEL LIST
### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
## lines between the AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST markers will be modified
## by the debian update-grub script except for the default options below
## DO NOT UNCOMMENT THEM, Just edit them to your needs
## ## Start Default Options ##
## default kernel options
## default kernel options for automagic boot options
## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
# kopt=root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro
## default grub root device
## e.g. groot=(hd0)
# groot=(hd0)
## should update-grub create alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. alternative=true
##      alternative=false
# alternative=true
## should update-grub lock alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. lockalternative=true
##      lockalternative=false
# lockalternative=false
## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
## alternatives
## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
# defoptions=console=hvc0
## should update-grub lock old automagic boot options
## e.g. lockold=false
##      lockold=true
# lockold=false
## Xen hypervisor options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenhopt=
## Xen Linux kernel options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenkopt=console=tty0
## altoption boot targets option
## multiple altoptions lines are allowed
## e.g. altoptions=(extra menu suffix) extra boot options
##      altoptions=(recovery) single
# altoptions=(recovery mode) single
## controls how many kernels should be put into the menu.lst
## only counts the first occurence of a kernel, not the
## alternative kernel options
## e.g. howmany=all
##      howmany=7
# howmany=all
## specify if running in Xen domU or have grub detect automatically
## update-grub will ignore non-xen kernels when running in domU and vice versa
## e.g. indomU=detect
##      indomU=true
##      indomU=false
# indomU=true
## should update-grub create memtest86 boot option
## e.g. memtest86=true
##      memtest86=false
# memtest86=true
## should update-grub adjust the value of the default booted system
## can be true or false
# updatedefaultentry=false
## should update-grub add savedefault to the default options
## can be true or false
# savedefault=false
## ## End Default Options ##
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-28-generic
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro console=hvc0 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-26-generic
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro console=hvc0 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19.0-26-generic (recovery mode)
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.4.0-1068-fips
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1068-fips root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro console=hvc0 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1068-fips
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.4.0-1068-fips (recovery mode)
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1068-fips root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1068-fips
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 4.4.0-1083-fips
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1083-fips root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro console=hvc0 
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1083-fips
title       Ubuntu 22.10, kernel 4.4.0-1083-fips (recovery mode)
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1083-fips root=UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd ro  single
initrd      /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1083-fips
title       Ubuntu 22.10, memtest86+
root        (hd0)
kernel      /boot/memtest86+.bin
### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-1068-fips   a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1083-fips   a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic   a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-26-generic   a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a00cbbed-d379-43df-b765-0dcd83fd91bd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5d36fa99-ed26-4cec-9329-015463d13ad7 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=â€ipv6.disable=1 quiet splashâ€
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=â€ipv6.disable=1â€³

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   8.897037506 = 9.553121280    boot/grub/menu.lst                             1
  43.375019073 = 46.573572096   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  25.075359344 = 26.924462080   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  67.402774811 = 72.373178368   boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1083-fips                   1
  95.254455566 = 102.278692864  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic                 2
  90.926338196 = 97.631412224   boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic                 1
  81.553016663 = 87.566884864   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1068-fips                   1
  90.926338196 = 97.631412224   vmlinuz                                        1
  95.254455566 = 102.278692864  vmlinuz.old                                    2
  94.610347748 = 101.587087360  boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1083-fips                5
  90.000972748 = 96.637808640   boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic              9
  10.375972748 = 11.141115904   boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic              6
  78.915035248 = 84.734373888   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1068-fips                7
  71.183258057 = 76.432441344   boot/initrd.img-linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic  1
  10.375972748 = 11.141115904   initrd.img                                     6
  90.000972748 = 96.637808640   initrd.img.old                                 9

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Sep 19 19:30 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43263 Sep 19 19:30 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Sep 19 19:30 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Sep 19 19:30 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Sep 19 19:30 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Sep 19 19:30 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Sep 19 19:30 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to cleanup legacy in /boot) and reinstall the grub2 of
sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s
```

Can anyone help? I tried doing this by searching at almost all the forums and couldn't fix this.

Awaiting some positive fix in this matter.

Comment: You have some strange characters in your file `/etc/default/grub` which should be `"`. Two lines are affected, the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`. Correct these lines and try to update grub again.

Comment: And mv `/boot/grub/menu.lst`else there..